# Informix PDO y XAMPP

Tags: php, pdo, xampp, informix

saludos a todos y de antemano gracias a cualquier respuesta y/o ayuda que pueda recibir.

Tengo problemas para conectar PHP 5.6.24 de XAMPP a un Servidor INFORMIX que no esta en mi equipo local.

Instale el CSDK de Informix, hice la respectiva configuración y desde el conectTest me conecto correctamente a la Base de Datos y puedo hacer consultas de prueba desde ahi.

Ahora bien, en PHP no me funciona nada, descargue la librería php_pdo_informix.dll, la habilite en PHP.ini y reinicie Apache, todo bien, hago una simple conexión de prueba así:

```
try {
   $db = new PDO("informix:DSN=MyDSN", "srvapp", "miclave");
} catch (PDOException $e) {
   echo 'Error de Conexion: '. $e->getMessage();
}
```

y la respuesta que me devuelve es: could not find driver.

He visto un montón de POST y lo ponen muy fácil, pero realmente nada me funciona, toda la configuración si me funciona, me conecto y consulto, pero desde PHP nada.

Espero puedan ayudarme con este tema. Gracias

Saludos

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Aqui coloco el paso a paso a mi pregunta, ya funcionando.

**Instalar Driver Informix para PHP
Instalar Informix SDK**

```
export INFORMIXDIR=/opt/IBM/informix
PATH=$PATH:$INFORMIXDIR/bin
tar -xvf clientsdk.4.10.FC8DE.LINUX.tar
./installclientsdk
```

enter enter 1 enter enter enter enter enter

---

**Instalar PDO Informix**

```
apt-get install php5-dev
tar -xvzf PDO_INFORMIX-1.3.1.tgz
cd PDO_INFORMIX-1.3.1/
phpize --with-php-config=/usr/bin/php-config
./configure --with-php-config=/usr/bin/php-config
```

Va a tirar que no encuentra php_pdo_driver.h, y hay que editar el configure para que busque en **/usr/include/php5/ext/pdo/php_pdo_driver.h**

```
updatedb
locate php_pdo_driver.h
vi configure
```

**Correr nuevamente**

```
./configure --with-php-config=/usr/bin/php-config
```

Editar el Makefile y agregar **/opt/IBM/informix/lib/esql/checkapi.o**

```
vi Makefile
```

**Debe quedar asi**

```
PDO_INFORMIX_SHARED_LIBADD = -Wl,-rpath,/root/PDO_INFORMIX-1.3.1/. -
L/root/PDO_INFORMIX-1.3.1/. -Wl,-rpath,/opt/IBM/informix/lib/esql -
L/opt/IBM/informix/lib/esql -Wl,-rpath,/opt/IBM/informix/lib/cli -
L/opt/IBM/informix/lib/cli -Wl,-rpath,/opt/IBM/informix/lib -
L/opt/IBM/informix/lib -lifcli -lifdmr -lifsql -lifasf -lifgen -lifos -lifgls -ldl -lcrypt /opt/IBM/informix/lib/esql/checkapi.o -lifglx

make
make install
```

---

**Activar el driver en PHP**

```
cd /etc/php5/apache2/conf.d
echo "extension=pdo_informix.so" > pdo_informix.ini
```

---

**Habilitar las variables de Informix para Apache**

```
vi /etc/apache2/envvars
```

**Agregar al final**

```
export INFORMIXDIR=/opt/IBM/informix
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/opt/IBM/informix/lib:/opt/IBM/informix/lib/esql:/opt/IBM/informix/lib/cli:/opt/IBM/informix/lib/c++:/opt/IBM/informix/lib/client:/opt/IBM/informix/lib/dmi
```

**Reiniciar Apache**

```
/etc/init.d/apache2 restart
```

---

**Para Probar**

```
 vi /opt/IBM/informix/etc/sqlhosts
```

**Agregar al final**

```
host  protocolo  ip  puerto
```

**Crear un php con lo siguiente**

```
<?php phpinfo();?>
```

En la sección de PDO debemos ver el pdo_informix

Luego se crea un archivo en PHP de conexión y probamos que todo este bien.

Me costo un poco de tiempo y ayuda de un compañero , pero al final logramos instalar el driver en PHP 5.6.30

Saludos y espero les sirva si quieren conectar a Informix con PHP

Answer (score 0):

Ese Mensaje sale porque PHP no te reconoce la dll, lo puedes confirmar en el php_info(), revisando, solo hay dll de la versión php 5.4 para abajo, para las nuevas versiones de php solo se puede instalar en linux.

Un colega logro conseguir la dll para la versión 5.6 pero en estos momentos no la tengo como para publicarla.

De todas formas dejo el link :
https://pecl.php.net/package/PDO_INFORMIX

Que tiene las dll para windows y paquetes para linux.